# Do these go to eleven? (reputation points from upvote)

Tags: bug, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

The only reputation points gains I've received today are from upvotes on answers and chosen answers. The sum of all reputation from upvotes is 201.

[image]

Is this a bug? Or am I not understanding an element of the calculation?

---

***Later in the day...***

[image]

Comment: Did you downvote something?

Comment: @Mysticial not today

Comment: I feel like you're familiar with this, @Mysticial... Any chance you remember a previous report?

Comment: @Mysticial to correct my comment, I did but retracted it as Shog9 stated.

Comment: @Shog9 That was years ago and I don't think I ever filed a proper report for it. In my case, it was unupvote events. IIRC, I pinged you in chat about it, but that was it. It hasn't happened in a while though.

Comment: I now suspect that the bug you're talking about was fixed by the same change that introduced this one, @Mysticial...

Comment: I would upvote, but it's already gone up to eleven.

Comment: [recursion](http://imgur.com/bveIY2E) ^

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What's going on is this: earlier in the day, you downvoted an answer (-1). Then later on, you retracted that downvote (+1). Those two should cancel each other out, but the system doesn't do a full recalc under normal circumstances, it just sums up certain qualifying events for the day and if the sum is under 200 it continues giving you rep.

That partial sum counts the cost of downvotes but not the refund for retracting them. So by the time you hit the rep cap, it thought you were at 199 for the day instead of 200 and gave you one last point for the relevant upvote.

Eventually, a full recalc will run on your account and you'll lose the invalid point.

Comment: So that I'm clear.  Your explanation implies that I down voted prior to recalculation and retracted that down vote subsequent to recalculation?  Also, could I correct this by the elegant method of deleting and un-deleting my own post?

Comment: There (hasn't yet) been a recalc; the system just does a simple sum for the day every time someone votes. And that simple sum ignores undownvotes that happen during the day, so if you undownvote *at all* and hit the rep cap you'll run into this. And yes, deleting + undeleting a post would trigger a recalc.

Comment: This happens to me all the time; hitting rep caps, downvoting answers, and being downvoted sometimes all conspire to have the calculations go slightly wonky for a few days at a time.

Comment: FWIW, my gut feeling is this latest variant of this bug (there have been others before) started with the documentation project introduction.

Comment: Good eye there, @Martijn... I reviewed the change that was made to add Docs rep to this. The previous logic was driven directly from the votes table, and ignore deleted (== retracted) votes; the new logic is driven from the rep history entries that are created *from* votes, and fails to take into account retractions - so this would've been introduced then. Which means I can probably stop looking for a duplicate, since it's actually pretty new!

Comment: Would a downvote on an answer that later gets deleted also cause this?

Comment: @MartijnPieters not as wonky as my rep when the rep apocalypse happened (docs) - I had constant 250+ rep without the cap - it was confusing to say the least. (I went up to 6000 rep before the changes :D)

Comment: @Mafii: Oh, I do remember the docrepocalypse, it's why I noticed the bug returning in the first place ;-)

Comment: How exactly does that get him a +11 on a specific answer? He cannot vote on his own answer, so the undownvote of +1 should be from a different answer, while the +10 should be on his own answer.

Comment: Two votes from two voters on one answer, @MaskedMan. First one gave 10 (as such votes normally do), second gave 1 as the system thought he was 1 point away from the cap. Both the -1 for the downvote and +1 for the retraction were on a different post much earlier in the day (and since they both occurred in the same day, both would've been redacted from the visible rep history!)

Comment: If the two votes were from two different voters, then why is it shown as +11 on a single line, as against two separate lines of +10 and +1? If he wasn't close to repcap, it wouldn't have shown two votes as +20 on a single line, right? Also, if the system thought he was about to hit the repcap, then why did he get a further +10 immediately after that?

Comment: The time sort rolls up votes, @masked - you can observe this in other places in the screenshots too. The timestamp is the first vote in the series of (not necessarily consecutive) votes to the answer. So yes, if he wasn't close to the cap it would've shown +20, followed by the +10 that actually occurred in between the two +10s that were rolled up.